# Range of a distribution function of a law concentrated on the rational number

Tags: probability

This is an exercise problem (9.1.10) in Dudley's Real Analysis and Probability. The problem is as followed:

Let $F$ be the distribution function of a probability law $P$ concentrated on the set $\mathbb{Q}$ of rational numbers, so that $P(\mathbb{Q}) = 1$. Let $H$ be the range of $F$. Prove or disprove:
(a) $H$ is always countable. (Hint: use the inversion of the Cantor function)
(B) $H$ always has Lebesgue measure 0.